# How can I connect to Stack Overflow with a mobile phone?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, mobile-web, user-experience

I plan to buy a mobile phone. After getting motivated by [Jon Skeet's schedule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-does-jon-skeet-never-sleep) :p, I realized that I have around 24 hours a week when I am free, and I am with my mobile phone. I love to be on Stack Overflow during this time, learning a lot.

Now, accessing Stack Overflow from a phone is one of my key requirements.

What is the experience of browsing Stack Overflow from a mobile?

Moreover, in the place where I live we don't have Wi-Fi, so I will have to rely on [GPRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service) connectivity.

Is there any app from Stack Exchange for accessing Stack Overflow without requiring too much bandwidth or any special UI for mobile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some read-only apps that use the stackapps API; however, *posting answers* should currently be via the main web-site. So one question is: what mobile browsers does it work on? I know it works OK from mobile safari, for example.

Another option is using your phone as the gateway for a laptop or netbook - or just use a laptop/netbook with GPRS capability (or a USB dongle). Of course, since you might want to test *code* a laptop seems the obvious thing anyway...

Comment: code compilation and execution are secondary things for me. Primary is to answer as efficiently as we are answering from keyboard of desktop of laptop , speed is also main requirement

Comment: @orglifejava - well, I regularly write answers from iPod - including this one...

Comment: I too use the mobile safari, and I really don't have anything bad to say about it. Until @MarcGravell figures out how to make the sites even more awesome. Just make it awesome Marc!! ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'm answering this question from an HTC Desire running the newest Android version. All site functions work like they do from a regular browser, except that a) code isn't monospaced (that's a bug in the android browser) and b) you don't get the Markdown preview when writing posts (SO disables it for mobile agents).

Comment: I'm commenting on this question on exactly the same platform. Yes, it works. But it is a little painful: you have to zoom into the central column every time you surf to a page (at which point all the stuff in the other columns becomes irrelevant cruft), and then you have things like titles overhanging to the left. Plus, as you scroll, you can wander off to one side. A slightly different mobile version with a single column and an 80/20-ruled set of controls would be great. Might be better on netbooks too!

Answer (score 1):

I got my Samsung Galaxy S two weeks ago, upgraded to Android 2.2, and I have answered a few questions from it since then. Just one important note - when clicking on your "Interesting tags", zoom-in enough, so that you can't accidentally press the "x" and delete the tag. I deleted 2-3 of mine already.

Update: the captcha is not working. So if you try multiple submits, you'd have to close and wait.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Motorola Droid 2, and I can second what [balpha said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71342/question-for-stackoverflow-mobile-users/71352#71352): everything appears to work as usual except for code not being displayed in a monospaced/fixed-width font and the absence of a Markdown preview when posting.

The only other small annoyance I've found is that the pull-out keyboard doesn't appear to have a backtick key anywhere, which is used for making [`inline code spans`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). The *virtual* keyboard has one, but what's the point of using that when you have a pull-out keyboard? You just end up losing screen real estate.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [StackMobile.com](https://stackmobile.com/) specifically for this very purpose.

It has been tested on a number of different mobile browsers and formats questions and answers in a way that is both easy and intuitive for mobile browsers.

[image]

Opera Mini:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wapreview.com](http://wapreview.com/images/StackMobile.jpeg))</sub>

---

**Note:** this site is read-only due to limitations of the API right now. However, you can quickly jump to the corresponding StackExchange page at any time by clicking the site's icon in the upper-right corner of every page.